# Windows service using WCF or .Net Remoting service

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-remoting

I want to create a Windows Service (CS) which shall keep some data objects in memory for 12 hours or more. This windows service (CS) shall call a WCF service (DS) or Database to populate the reference data.

From the Web Site (WS), I need to access those data objects from the windows service (CS) so that I dont need to call WCF service or Database.

Earlier I achieved something similar to this by using .NET Remoting (MarshalByRefObject).

I am trying to something similar to distributed caching. Reference data calls from web site to WCF service or database take longer time. So I planned to have Windows (WCF) service which loads all the reference data during off-peak hours and keep it in its memory. My web site will directly access the data objects from memory.

How can I do that same in WCF ? I mean achieving .Net Remoting in WCF...

Update: Thanks everyone. I created a WCF Library and hosted in Windows service. Have a static hashtable to keep the data objects in memory. Clients access the objects using TCP. Its fast now.

Thanks
JK

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not clear at all.. Please give us some example of what you need to do. Also I don't understand why you don't want you website to access directly to your WCF services and Database. Adding the layer with the window service is just gonna slow the process

Comment: You can host a WCF service in a Windows service quite easily.  There are a number of examples on how to do this on the web - here's one from Microsoft:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

Comment: @Guigui I am trying to something similar to distributed caching. Reference data calls from web site to WCF service or database take longer time. So I planned to have Windows (WCF) service which loads all the reference data during off-peak hours and keep it in its memory. My web site will directly access the data objects from memory.

Comment: if you have expirience with .net remoting, maybe this link will help you...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @sine I tried with the link you sent. But I am getting the connection error. Should I change the file name to ".svc" ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I created a WCF Library and hosted in Windows service. Have a static hashtable to keep the data objects in memory. Clients access the objects using TCP. Its fast now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, what you are looking for is a cache server such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org/). There are a number of .NET clients available for these and other such technologies. For Redis, I suggest you check out the [ServiceStack Redis client](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/).

Comment: Thanks Tyler. Still we are researching on Redis and Memcached. But considering the configuration and usage, i feel it is easy to build a home grown solution.